# Has anyone succeeded in installing Mono (the Linux .NET framework project) on the red hat enterprise?

Tags: linux, mono

Has anyone succeeded in installing Mono (the Linux .NET framework project) on the red hat linux enterprise?

Comment: Should be asked at: http://superuser.com/

Comment: Really, this is a dev issue and was asked at the appropriate place. It should not have been migrated to Server Fault, which is for system administration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I compiled from source.